# VB.NET Debug Error

Tags: vb.net, debugging, illegal-characters

I get this error "Illegal characters in path" for this code:

```
Dim strm As System.IO.FileStream
strm = New System.IO.FileStream(filepath, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
```

Comment: What's the filepath?

Comment: Learn how to use the watch window to track variable values. Illegal characters are listed in IO.Path.InvalidPathChars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file path might contain an invalid character that Windows file system not allow to use it like `\ / : * ? " < > |`